# How to launch french qwerty keyboard from the application?

Tags: android

I have to launch french language supported qwerty keyboard when user taps on the Edit text of the activity.please help me with example.

Regards,
Amit

Comment: Maybe you mean a Canadian French keyboard? In France, keyboards are `AZERTYUIOP` not `QWERTY` in their topmost letters keys row (2nd row from top, below digits).

Comment: okay, thanks for this information but how to launch it from my app? as I know android device supports french local by default but when i clicked on the Edit text it is poping up keyboard with all english charcters.